should on_fetch handler in Cloudflare workers be async or not?
I'm learning to use Cloudflare workers in Python language, and I tried the code below:
# src/entry.py
from js import Response

async def on_fetch(request):
    return Response.new("hello world")


or
# src/entry.py
from js import Response

def on_fetch(request):
    return Response.new("hello world")


My question is: which one of above follows the standard?
Or, Cloudflare workers server is compatible with both? May I ask in which fragment of workerd's code the magic is?
I tried them both. Both works, and both are mentioned in document https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/languages/python/ .
